# Prove that $f$ is the identically zero function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, solution-verification, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Let $f : [0,1] \times [0,1] \longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function. Suppose that $$\int_{0}^{1} \left ( \int_{0}^{1} f(x,y)\ dy \right ) dx = 0.$$ Prove that $f$ is the identically zero function.

**My attempt** $:$ $f$ is a non-negative measurable function on $[0,1] \times [0,1].$ So by Tonelli's theorem we have $$\iint_{[0,1] \times [0,1]} f(x,y)\ dx\ dy = \int_{0}^{1} \left ( \int_{0}^{1} f(x,y)\ dy \right ) dx = 0.$$ So if there exists $\textbf {x}_0= (x_0,y_0) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$ such that $f(\textbf {x}_0) > 0,$ by continuity of $f$ at $\textbf {x}_0$ there exists an open ball $B( \textbf {x}_0, \delta)$ of some radius $\delta > 0$ surrounding $\textbf {x}_0$ with $B(\textbf {x}_0, \delta) \subseteq [0,1] \times [0,1]$ such that for any $\textbf {x} = (x,y) \in B(\textbf {x}_0, \delta)$ we have $$f(\textbf {x}) \gt \frac {f(\textbf{x}_0)} {2 \pi {\delta}^2}.$$ Since $f$ is a non-negative function so we must have $$\frac {f(\textbf {x}_0 )} {2} \lt \iint_{B(\textbf {x}_0, \delta)} f(x,y)\ dx\ dy \leq \iint_{[0,1] \times [0,1]} f(x,y)\ dx\ dy = 0$$ a contradiction. This shows that $f \equiv 0$ on $[0,1] \times [0,1].$

Can anybody plaese check my proof to ascertain whether it holds good or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\frac {f(\textbf {x}_0 )} {2} \lt \iint_{B(\textbf {x}_0, \delta)} f(x,y)\ dx\ dy $ looks slightly unlikely to me.  Should the left hand side include the area of $B(\textbf {x}_0, \delta)$?

Comment: $x_0$ may not be an interior point of the square.

Comment: @Henry please have a look at my recent edit. The only issue is that $\textbf {x}_0$ might not be an interior point of $[0,1] \times [0,1].$

Comment: I am not quite sure $f(\textbf {x}) \gt \frac {f(\textbf{x}_0)} {2 \pi {\delta}^2}$ works either, since for small $\delta$ you may have $\frac {1} {2 \pi {\delta}^2} \gg 1$.  Instead I would try something like $f(\textbf {x}_0 )\frac {\pi {\delta}^2}{8} \lt \iint_{B(\textbf {x}_0, \delta)} f(x,y)\ dx\ dy$

Comment: @Henry very nice remark. Thanks for pointing that out. But I think anything less than $\frac {\pi {\delta}^2} {4}$ will work. Right? What I mean to say is that $$f(\textbf {x}_0)\ c < \iint_{B \left ( \textbf {x}_0, \delta \right )} f(x,y)\ dx\ dy,$$ for any real number $0 < c < \frac {\pi {\delta}^2} {4}.$ Is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems with your proof :

- If $\frac{f(x_0)}{2} < f(x)$ on $B(x_0,\delta)$, then this does not imply that $\iint_{B(x_0,\delta)} f(x,y)dxdy > \frac{f(x_0)}{2}$ because the measure of $B(x_0,\delta)$ could be much smaller than $1$. For example : the function $f(x) =2$ is bigger than $1$, but $\int_0^{0.01} f(x)dx = 0.02 < 1$.

The true fact is that $\iint_{B(x_0,\delta)} f(x,y)dxdy > \color{blue}{m(B(x_0,\delta))}\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$ where $m(\cdot)$ denotes the Lebesgue measure of the given set. Since this set definitely has Lebesgue measure non-zero, we know that the above statement is still one of significance : when this is continued with the statements you present, things look good :
$$
0 < \frac{f(x_0)}{2} < \iint_{B(x_0,\delta)} f(x,y)dxdy < \iint_{[0,1]^2} f(x,y)dxdy  = 0
$$

Contradiction.

---

- There is a second problem : $[0,1]^2$ is *not* open, so if the above $x_0$ is on the boundary of $[0,1]^2$ (say $x_0 = (0,0)$ for example) then we have the problem that $B(x_0,\delta)$ lies outside $[0,1]^2$ for any $\delta$, and the integral over such a ball is undefined because $f$ is undefined there.

To work around this is simple : simply take $S=B(x_0,\delta) \cap [0,1]^2$. All you need to do is replace the ball by $S$. But you need to make sure $S$ has non-zero measure : I am sure you can do this, take it as an exercise (hint : try to find a ball contained in $S$). Of course, then we just have :
$$
0 < \frac{f(x_0)}{2} < \iint_{B(x_0,\delta) \cap [0,1]^2} f(x,y)dxdy < \iint_{[0,1]^2} f(x,y)dxdy  = 0
$$

---

Following OP edits, the first problem was solved by taking $f(x_0)\over 2 \pi \delta^2$ instead of $\frac{f(x_0)}{2}$, which then multiplies with $\pi \delta^2 = m(B(x_0,\delta))$ to make OP's first issue null.

Comment: I think the first problem is solved. Please take a look at my edit.

Comment: Yes, the first problem is solved.

Comment: The second problem is also solved if we take the open neighbourhood of $\textbf {x}_0$ in subspace topology. Then $\pi \delta^2$ has to replaced by the area of that neighbourhood. Isn't it so?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: What I observed is that except the four corner points any points on the boundary of the closed unit square can be encircled by an open ball such that exactly half of it's portion is lying inside the closed unit square and the four corner points are encircled by an open ball such that exactly one fourth of it's portion is lying inside the closed unit square. So in those cases we need to replace $\pi \delta^2$ by $\frac {\pi \delta^2} {4}.$ So there is no issue of getting zero measure as you mentioned.

Comment: So the entire problem can be solved in exactly one step just by replacing $\pi \delta^2$ by $\frac {\pi {\delta}^2} {4}.$

Comment: @Anacardium Yes, that is good enough an observation for things to go through. Thanks for the acceptance.